# CodeIgniter Upload class PDF filetype not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

Works locally but on the two servers I've tried the same error message is shown. Using Codeigniter 2.1.3

```
private function upload_file(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|pdf';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = true;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    var_dump($_FILES);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
        die();
        return $error;
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($data);
        die();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

While doing the `var_dump($_FILES);` it shows the correct information 
`array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "0002.pdf" ["type"]=> string(14) "aplication/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\php9454.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(29295) } }`

`var_dump($error)` giving off `array(1) { ["error"]=> string(64) " The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. " }`

Tested with both a png and jpg and these works marvelously.

The correct mime-types are in the config file `config/mimes.php`

```
 'pdf'  =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download'),
```

Edit: If it means anything, the local server is a MAC and the two remotes are windows.

Comment: You are positive you uploaded the changes to the server? I only ask because you said it works locally.

Comment: Yeah I'm positive, this stuff went up months back. Just stopped working, unsure of when. I also added the var_dumps() and tested on the remote servers, so it's definitely got the up to date code

Comment: It just randomly stopped working? You probably need to find out if anyone has made any changes to the servers, apache, php config files or anything like that. Can you write a test upload script not using codeigniter and see if it allows you to upload a pdf file?

Comment: Servers both definitely running 2.1.3? There was a bug with the upload class in 2.1.0.

Comment: Yeah both are running 2.1.3, exact same code on both servers. @Danny still trying to get a script together, trying one locally and it's denying me to upload pdf...

Comment: This is a bit crazy, but try putting pdf at the beginning of the list or allowed types ` $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|jpg|png|jpeg|gif';`. Has been known to solve some problems like this.

Comment: Check out the answer I just put :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So even though the code is all correct the error is actually on PHP itself. There's a spelling mistake in there mime-types.
When `var_dump($_FILES)` it spitting out `["type"]=> string(14) "aplication/pdf"` Note that "application" is spelt wrong.

Checked on workmates machine and his correct, so might be an issue with php >5.3.5

Comment: Odd, does your local ouput the same spelling ?

Comment: Yeah it was on my local that I noticed the error, then came back to have a look if it was the same on the server (the dumps i did up in the question are from the server). And what do you know the mistakes there also

Comment: How are the pdfs made? Sounds like the whoever/however the pdfs are made the header is being set incorrectly.

Comment: If this is the case just add the misspelled mime to the CI mime config so it's `'pdf'  =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'aplication/pdf'),`

Comment: @Jeemusu will create a new pdf then try then. 
Cryptic Thanks, will do :)
Thing that confuses me is how was this working locally but not on the server? same file, same headers, different results

Comment: @Jeemusu tried a pdf from the client and get the same thing :/ odd. At least I know how to fix it now

Comment: Add "application/octet-stream" to the pdf key in mimes.php for pdf key.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue here for some reason I can't upload pdf files a quick troublshooting was to display errors

```
$msg = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
echo $msg;
```

I got the error message of invalid file type , so I added anew line of code to display full information about the file to uploaded.

```
$msg = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
$msg.=print_r($this->upload->data());
echo $msg;
```

then I copy the file type to config/mime.php

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf'),
```

and make sure that the same mime type is used as the mime type of my uploaded file.
The funny part was that the error was that in mime.php there was a typo :)

apostrophe instead of single quote as a result of copy past from internet without paying attention to quotation marks used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this->load->library('upload',$config);
```

Try this

`$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);`

This works for me