# Uploading a PDF with CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a pdf to my website using the CodeIgniter framework. Uploading a JPG or PNG works fine, but a PDF doesn't.

I have 2 forms on my page, but if I print out the 'userfile' post from my controller, I do get the filename of the pdf.

This is the code I have in my view:

```
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <?php
        $attributes = array('name' => 'vluchtkalenderForm', 'id' => 'vluchtkalenderForm');
        echo form_open('subgebruiker/uploadDocument', $attributes); //opening form with action at controller 'subgebruiker/uploadDocument'
        ?>
        <h3>Vluchtkalender</h3>
        <?php echo form_hidden('typeDocument', 'vluchtkalender'); ?> //hidden field to give the directory to upload to
        <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
        <span id="vluchtkalenderFout"></span>
        <br />
        <?php
        echo form_submit('vluchtkalenderForm', 'Document toevoegen');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <?php
        $attributes = array('name' => 'opleervluchtenForm', 'id' => 'opleervluchtenForm');
        echo form_open('subgebruiker/uploadDocument', $attributes);
        ?>
        <h3>Opleervluchten</h3>
        <?php echo form_hidden('typeDocument', 'opleervluchten'); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
        <span id="opleervluchtenFout"></span>
        <br />
        <?php
        echo form_submit('opleervluchtenForm', 'Document toevoegen');
        echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = 'application/userdocs/' . $this->input->post('typeDocument') . '/'; // 'typeDocument' contains part of the directory where to upload to
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $data["succesmelding"] = "Uploaden van document gelukt."; //upload worked
    } else {
        $data["foutmelding"] = "Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uploaden van het document."; //upload didn't work
    }
```

I also added this line in mimes.php in the config folder:

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download', 'application/unknown'),
```

EDIT:

Seems like something fixed it. I added these two lines of code in my controller and that did the job.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: Didn't get one. If I print_r($this->upload->data()); I get an empty array

Comment: check the below link it will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962158/codeigniter-upload-class-pdf-filetype-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following:

```
echo form_open_multipart('subgebruiker/uploadDocument', $attributes);
```

This is required as you are uploading a file with the form. It adds the `enctype= multipart/form-data` to the form declaration.

You may also change the `allowed_types` declaration if the above doesn't works:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; //the * for any mime type
```

Comment: I've already tried this and this doesn't work either. if I print_r I still get Array ( [file_name] => [file_type] => [file_path] => [full_path] => [raw_name] => [orig_name] => [client_name] => [file_ext] => [file_size] => [is_image] => [image_width] => [image_height] => [image_type] => [image_size_str] => )

Comment: Okay, please update your question then, with form_open_multipart.